# Wildcard universal link confirmation

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I have a question about iOS universal link wild-card support.

I have the a few hundred sub-domains within my domain, say:
 1. subdomain1.example.com
 2. subdomain2.example.com
 3. subdomain3.example.com
 ...

I am putting my JSON file in root DNS @ https://example.com/apple-app-site-association. My goal is to not needing to add JSON file in each of the subdomains and just put into root.

It seems that wild-card support is really about not needing to specify all the subdomains in the xCode entitlement PLIST rather than wild-card server-side (just populate in 1 place and be done).

Is there anyway to populate 1 JSON file at root to handle for all subdomains?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately no. The `apple-app-site-association` file needs to be available on every single subdomain, and without any redirects. The wildcard matching for subdomains is only for the `applinks` entries in Xcode.

You might be able to configure some sort of proxying setup that serves the same file behind the scenes for every subdomain, but this would depend on your server configuration.

Comment: I've tried to add a wild card app links in my entitlement file and it's not working. *.example.com. 

I need to add subdomain1.example.com to have that URL launch my app. This seems wrong. Is wild card even supported? (I'm on iOS 10 and min deployment target is iOS 10).

Comment: Wildcard applinks entitlements are definitely supported on iOS 10. Just not in the `apple-app-site-association` file.

Comment: I confirmed that both subdomain1.example.com/apple-app-site-association and example.com/apple-app-site-association is needed for wild card to work.